Delete with vim-surround in visual mode
I want to highlight some word and delete the asterisks
for example the sentenace bellow:
<u>*Build and Run with Docker*</u>

I highlight Build and Run with Docker and then what? If i do d it deletes the highlight, if I do S it inserts new asterisks.
What is the correct vim-surround command to delete/change surrounding in visual mode

Read vim-surround help page :help surround
Using the vim-surround plugin, you can delete the surrounding * using ds* in normal mode

I am using vim with vscode and intellij and the :help command doesn't exist on those implamentations.

Unsure about vim-surround support with vscode vim plugin, here you can find the help doc :help surround
